# Get around without custom editors and converters in Spring data

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-rest

Forgive me for the lengthy and descriptive question. Thanks for taking time to read this through.

I have a custom spring data rest implementation on top of my persistence layer. 
Instead of using primitive types, I use UUID as the id type of the objects being 
persisted.

I have a repository like this:

```
public interface DummyRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Dummy, UUID> { }
```

I have my custom DummyController to do GET and POST to the repository like this:

```
@RestController
public class DummyController {

@Autowired
DummyRepository dummyRepository;

@Autowired
DummyResourceProcessor processor;

@RequestMapping(value="/dummies", method = POST,     
consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Resource<Dummy>> createDummy(@RequestBody Dummy   
dummy){

    Dummy save = dummyRepository.save(dummy);
    Resource<Dummy> dummyResource = new Resource<Dummy>(save);
    return new  
    ResponseEntity<Resource<Dummy>>processor.process(dummyResource), 
    HttpStatus.CREATED);
  }

@RequestMapping(value="/dummies/{id}", method = GET,   
 produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
 public ResponseEntity<Resource<Dummy>> getDummy(@PathVariable("id") 
 Dummy dummy){

    Resource<Dummy> dummyResource = new Resource<Dummy>(save);
    return new ResponseEntity<Resource<Dummy>>
    (processor.process(dummyResource), HttpStatus.OK);
 }
}
```

When the dummy objects are being saved, a UUID is generated and is assigned to
the id field before persisting it. 
In my resource-processor, the links are being set like this:

```
@Component
public class DummyResourceProcessor implements  
ResourceProcessor<Resource<Dummy>> {

  @Override
  public Resource<Dummy> process(Resource<Dummy> resource) {
    Dummy dummy = resource.getContent();     
    resource.add(linkTo(methodOn(DummyController.class).
      getDummy(dummy)).withSelfRel());
    return resource;
  }
}
```

From my test code I do a POST using like this:

```
    result =
    mockMvc.perform(
            post("/dummies").content("{\"name\":\"TestDummy\"}")  
             .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
             .andDo(print())
             .andExpect(status().isCreated()).andReturn();
```

And I get something like this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.util.UUID] to required type [java.lang.String] for property 'id': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:287)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:461)
... 72 more
{"cause":null,"message":"No converter found capable of converting from   
type @org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable 
com.sudo.Dummy to type java.lang.String"}
```

This was fixed using a DummyToStringConvertor which essentially looks like this:

```
public class DummyToStringConverter implements Converter<Dummy, String> {

 @Override
 public String convert(Dummy dummy) {
  return dummy.getId().toString();
 }
}
```

Then I do a GET like this:

```
String dummyLocation = result.getResponse().getHeader("Location");
result =
    mockMvc.perform(get(dummyLocation)).andExpect(status().
    isOk())..andExpect(jsonPath("$.name").value("TestDummy"))
   .andDo(print()).andReturn();
```

And I get back this:

```
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type   
'com.sudo.Dummy'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException
:Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type  
[com.sudo.Dummy]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

This was fixed using a custom editor class so as to convert the String back to Dummy object:

```
public class DummyEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {

  private final DummyRepository dummyRepository;

  public DummyEditor(DummyRepository dummyRepository) {
     this.dummyRepository = dummyRepository;
  }

  @Override
  public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
     Dummy dummy = dummyRepository.findOne(UUID.fromString(text));
     setValue(dummy);
  }
 }
```

In the controller I added this using @Initbinder. And it stopped
complaining.

My working theory is that while generating the link inside the dummy 
resourceprocessor, during the call to the method (although its not executed, 
I believe), the @PathVariable annotation expects an "id" but it gets a Dummy 
object and it breaks because it is not able to convert this into the String 
(URI template). Is this right ? If not, why is the Dummy object not being 
resolved automatically during the link generation? Is it because of the UUID 
field ? When I save the id of a Dummy object as a String and change the 
repository signature from UUID to String, then everything works as expected. Is 
there any way to circumvent this problem without resorting to the use of custom 
converters and editors ?

Answer (score 0):

Both exceptions had nothing to do with the link generation code. Both the exceptions were raised trying to parse the request body and parameters respectively.

You got the first exception because request body was unable to convert your input Json to `Dummy` object. Because of the `UUID` type for id. Problem was fixed when you implemented the converter.

Second exception was raised during the GET call because Spring is trying to convert `{id}` placeholder `String` value to `Dummy` object and it did not know how to do it. If you change the method signatures of your `GET`  method as shown below, you should be good. You will not require `PropertyEditorSupport`.

```
public ResponseEntity<Resource<Dummy>> getDummy(@PathVariable("id") 
 String dummyId){
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So this means that inside the GET, I will have to fetch the dummy having the id (in the parameter) explicitly using a dummyrepository object. Hmmm. Also, this means that I always have to use the DummyToString convertor. Could you also perhaps shed some light on the question of why is it that when I resort to custom controllers,  do these conversions come in the way whereas Spring Data Rest seems to do all that automatically ?

Comment: Yes to your first statement. Can you elaborate what custom controllers you are talking about?

Comment: Custom controllers as in the DummyController that I have written explicitly for POST and GET rather than resorting to Spring Data Rest (as in the example in the question.)

Comment: Since you have defined a custom controller with the routes /dummies and /dummies/{id}. Any time you hit these routes Spring will resolve them to DummyController. It's like overriding the default behavior and you want to take control of the response generation. And yes you would need a converter. You can define it once and it can be used across all the controllers. You can read more about converters here http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#core-convert.

Comment: Okay. Clear. So, this whole conversion problem wouldn't have surfaced if I had used String/Long or a primitive type ? Is this solely because of using UUID type for the id ? If I had used String/Long for the id type of the Dummy object, I guess it should be possible to use Dummy object directly in the GET method instead of id  (of type String) ?

Comment: Yes, Spring REST is good at converting primitive types. If you want it to parse a special type then you have to go through Conversion Service route. However your last statement about passing Dummy Object in GET is  not correct. You make a GET request /dummies/{id}. {id} place holder is a String value. So input of getDummy method will always be String and Output will be Resource<Dummy> irrespective of Dummy object has property id with primitive type.

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot Nitin and really appreciate you taking time and patience to answer. One more question. You said that we override the default behaviour and take control of response generation when we write our own controllers. Is this also the reason why that I have to invoke the `resourceprocessor.process` method explicitly ? Spring Data seems to do that automatically. Or can this triggered somehow so that the resourceprocessor of the corresponding type can be triggered automatically ?

Comment: ResourceProcessor provides you more control over the response generation of an entity during the serialization of the response. If you are not doing anything different than the default response, then you can get rid of the resource processor. There are multiple ways of doing the same thing checkout this example where ResourceSupport is used to generate HATEOAS elements in the controller itself https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-hateoas/

Comment: It is not a default response per se, I add my own links to my Dummy resource in the resource processor. So it is important that this needs to be invoked so that the links are set in the dummy resource before it is sent back as response.

Comment: I don't think so. Try removing the explicit call to processor in your controller. I think it will be called automatically. Just the definition needs to be there. Here is the example https://github.com/olivergierke/spring-restbucks/blob/master/src%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Forg%2Fspringsource%2Frestbucks%2Fpayment%2Fweb%2FPaymentOrderResourceProcessor.java